# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC : how do I bind to a nested collection?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC (not Razor), how do I bind to a nested collection? The last time I did this was a few years ago using ASP.NET 4.6.2. Then, my code included the snippets below.

When I try all that code in a new ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC application, it's all broken. I'm just wondering is there a better way to bind a nested collection property in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC?

`ApplicationSettingsDto` (view model)

```
public class ApplicationSettingsDto
{
    public string DocumentUploadsFolder { get; set; }
    public string InventoryUploadsFolder { get; set; }
    public string CsvUploadsFolder { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Increment File Names if Exist")]
    public bool IncrementAssetFilenamesIfExist { get; set; }

    public List<TransactionFilterDto> TransactionFilters { get; set; }
}
```

`TransactionFilterDto` (nested list):

```
public class TransactionFilterDto
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Regex { get; set; }
    
    public PaymentFrequency PaymentFrequency { get; set; }
    
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The `Create` view included the following

```
        <div class="card top-buffer-md">
        <details open>
            <summary class="card-header bg-secondary text-white">Transaction Filters</summary>
            <div class="card-body">
                <fieldset class="top-buffer-md">
                    <ul id="transactionfilter-container" style="list-style-type: none">
                        @if (Model.TransactionFilters != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var group in Model.TransactionFilters)
                            {
                                Html.RenderPartial("_TransactionFilter", group);
                            }
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <a id="add-ag" href="#">Add Transaction Filter</a>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </details>
    </div>
```

The `_TransactionFilter.cshtml` partial view

```
@using Home.DPS.Web.Extensions
@model Home.DPS.Domain.Models.TransactionFilterDto

<li>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TransactionFilters"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Name" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 my-1">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentFrequency, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Frequency" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentFrequency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">$</div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Regex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", placeholder = "Regex" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Regex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('li').remove();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</li>
```

I was using the following extensions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace Home.DPS.Web.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        private const string JQueryTemplatingEnabledKey = "__BeginCollectionItem_jQuery";

        /// <summary>
        /// Begins a collection item by inserting either a previously used .Index hidden field value for it or a new one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="html"></param>
        /// <param name="collectionName">The name of the collection property from the Model that owns this item.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string collectionName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(collectionName))
                throw new ArgumentException("collectionName is null or empty.", nameof(collectionName));

            var collectionIndexFieldName = $"{collectionName}.Index";

            string itemIndex = null;

            if (html.ViewData.ContainsKey(JQueryTemplatingEnabledKey))
            {
                itemIndex = "${index}";
            }
            else
            {
                itemIndex = GetCollectionItemIndex(collectionIndexFieldName);
            }

            var collectionItemName = $"{collectionName}[{itemIndex}]";
            var indexField = new TagBuilder("input");
            indexField.MergeAttributes(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "name", collectionIndexFieldName },
                { "value", itemIndex },
                { "type", "hidden" },
                { "autocomplete", "off" }
            });

            html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(indexField.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            var result = new CollectionItemNamePrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, collectionItemName);
            return result;
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString CollectionItemJQueryTemplate<TModel, TCollectionItem>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            string partialViewName,
            TCollectionItem modelDefaultValues)
        {
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TCollectionItem>(modelDefaultValues);
            viewData.Add(JQueryTemplatingEnabledKey, true);
            return html.Partial(partialViewName, modelDefaultValues, viewData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to reuse old .Index values from the HttpRequest in order to keep the ModelState consistent
        /// across requests. If none are left returns a new one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collectionIndexFieldName"></param>
        /// <returns>a GUID string</returns>
        private static string GetCollectionItemIndex(string collectionIndexFieldName)
        {
            var previousIndices = (Queue<string>)HttpContext.Current.Items[collectionIndexFieldName];
            if (previousIndices == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items[collectionIndexFieldName] = previousIndices = new Queue<string>();

                var previousIndicesValues = HttpContext.Current.Request[collectionIndexFieldName];
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(previousIndicesValues))
                {
                    foreach (var index in previousIndicesValues.Split(','))
                        previousIndices.Enqueue(index);
                }
            }

            return previousIndices.Count > 0 ? previousIndices.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        
        private class CollectionItemNamePrefixScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TemplateInfo _templateInfo;
            private readonly string _previousPrefix;

            public CollectionItemNamePrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string collectionItemName)
            {
                this._templateInfo = templateInfo;

                _previousPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = collectionItemName;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = _previousPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does " it's all broken" mean. What is the issue with the code provided?

Comment: As an example, there's no loner a static HttpContext.  ViewDataDictionary constructor is different.  TagBuilder.ToString is broken.  html. There are several other examples. I was trying not to be over verbose in my original post. The question really more relates to the ask - if there are better ways to do this now in Asp.Net 6 rather than trying to fix the older version.

Comment: What do you really want? Migrating your codes from .netframework to .Net core or just find a solution that could  create ApplicationSettingsDto with mutipule TransactionFilterDto and send it to controller successfully?